# Proving symmetry and transitivity

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I want to prove $\mathbb{N} \sim \mathbb{Z}$ by indication of a bijection, thus the equipotency of the two sets. I know that I have to prove reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity. The reflexivity would be the identity map $f(x) = x$ on $\mathbb{N}$. For symmetry I would have to show two functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ and $f^{-1}: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. But what would be such functions?
I also don't know how to show transitivity, since I don't have a third set.

How would I prove symmetry and transitivity?

Comment: I think you want to show that these sets are in 1-1 correspondence.

Comment: What kind of similarity do you mean? Under what relation? Do you mean equinumerous?

Comment: I want to show that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have the same number of elements, which means a bijection exists between them.

Comment: There is no need to show reflexivity, symmetry or transitivity when trying to show the cardinality of two sets is equal. I think you may be confusing some definitions.

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$, defined by $\begin{cases}\frac{n}{2}\text{ if } n\text{ even }\\\frac{-n-1}{2}\text{ if } n\text{ odd }\end{cases}$. Then we have that $f$ maps the even numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ onto the nonnegative integers and the odd numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ onto the negative integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to prove reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity. You need to show a bijection exists, which (if you are exhibiting one) means proving surjectivity and injectivity. You want a function $f: \Bbb {N \to Z}$ that meets these requirements.  If you take the odd numbers of $\Bbb N$ to the nonnegative ones of $\Bbb Z$ and the evens of $\Bbb N$ to the negative ones of $\Bbb Z$ you can get there.